# Does struct with a single member have the same performance as a member type?

Tags: c, performance, struct, member

Does `struct` with a single member have the same performance as a member type (memory usage and speed)?

**Example**:

This code is a `struct` with a single member:

```
struct my_int
{
    int value;
};
```

is the performance of `my_int` same as `int` ?

Comment: Performance how? How would you use it compared to e.g. a normal `int` Variable? Have you tried to benchmark it?

Comment: It's more typing to use it, so it's "less performant" in that sense. Apart from that, look at the assembly generated by your compiler. (And/or benchmark.)

Comment: I guess OOTB value types are optimized in some ways but i don't think that you even notice the difference.

Answer (score 7):

Agree with [@harper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19877859/2410359) overall, but watch out for the following:

A classic difference is seen with a "unstructured" array and an array in a structure.

```
char s1[1000];
// vs
typedef struct {
  char s2[1000];
} s_T;
s_T s3;
```

When calling functions ...

```
void f1(char s[1000]);
void f2(s_T s);
void f3(s_T *s);

// Significant performance difference is not expected.
// In both, only an address is passed.
f1(s1);
f1(s3.s2);

// Significant performance difference is expected.
// In the second case, a copy of the entire structure is passed.
// This style of parameter passing is usually frowned upon.
f1(s1);
f2(s3);

// Significant performance difference is not expected.
// In both, only an address is passed.
f1(s1);
f3(&s3);
```

Answer (score 5):

In some cases, the ABI may have specific rules for returning structures and passing them to functions. For example, given

```
struct S { int m; };
struct S f(int a, struct S b);
int g(int a, S b);
```

calling `f` or `g` may, for example, pass `a` in a register, and pass `b` on the stack. Similarly, calling `g` may use a register for the return value, whereas calling `f` may require the caller to set up a location where `f` will store its result.

The performance differences of this should normally be negligible, but one case where it could make a significant difference is when this difference enables or disables tail recursion.

Suppose `g` is implemented as `int g(int a, struct S b) { return g(a, b).m; }`. Now, on an implementation where `f`'s result is returned the same way as `g`'s, this may compile to (actual output from clang)

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .text
        .globl  g
        .align  16, 0x90
        .type   g,@function
g:                                      # @g
        .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
        jmp     f                       # TAILCALL
.Ltmp0:
        .size   g, .Ltmp0-g
        .cfi_endproc


        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

However, on other implementations, such a tail call is not possible, so if you want to achieve the same results for a deeply recursive function, you really need to give `f` and `g` the same return type or you risk a stack overflow. (I'm aware that tail calls are not mandated.)

This *doesn't* mean `int` is faster than `S`, nor does it mean that `S` is faster than `int`, though. The memory use would be similar regardless of whether `int` or `S` is used, so long as the same one is consistently used.

Answer (score 3):

If the compiler has any penalty on using structs instead of single variables is strictly compiler and compiler options dependent.

But there are no reasons why the compiler should make any differences when your struct contains only one member. There should be additional code necessary to access the member nor to derefence any pointer to such an struct. If you don't have this oversimplified structure with one member deferencing might cost one addtional CPU instruction depending on the used CPU.

Answer (score -1):

A minimal example w/ GCC 10.2.0 -O3 gives exactly the same output i.e. no overhead introduced by struct:

```sh
diff -u0 <(

gcc -S -o /dev/stdout -x c -std=gnu17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra - <<EOF
// Out of the box
void OOTB(int *n){
  *n+=999;
}
EOF

) <(

gcc -S -o /dev/stdout -x c -std=gnu17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra - <<EOF
// One member struct
typedef struct { int inq_n; } inq;
void OMST(inq *n){
  n->inq_n+=999;
}
EOF

)
```

```
--- /dev/fd/63  [...]
+++ /dev/fd/62  [...]
@@ -4,3 +4,3 @@
-   .globl  OOTB
-   .type   OOTB, @function
-OOTB:
+   .globl  OMST
+   .type   OMST, @function
+OMST:
@@ -13 +13 @@
-   .size   OOTB, .-OOTB
+   .size   OMST, .-OMST
```

Not sure about more realistic/complex situations.